# Update UI from CursorAdapter onClick

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a listView that when a user clicks on the cardView I am calling a web service from an employeeNumber tied to that position. I get the data of the new web service call onResponse from OkHttp3s enqueue. How do I update the listView to populate the new data from the response?

Really lost as I know the listView is using the adapter which the on click is made. So not sure how to call the listView, to populate the adapter after the response is completed.

My MainActivity where the first ListView is populated and the adapter is attached.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private int mStartingEmployeeID = myStartingID;
    private String table = "employees";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OneTeam";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        getXMLData();

        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);
    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                     dbHandler.addEmployee(e);

                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        displayTopList();
                        displayBottomList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayTopList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mTopListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        ListView mTopListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(this, mTopListCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
    }

    public void displayBottomList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mBottomListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);

        ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mBottomListCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(false);
    }
}
```

The CursorAdapter that has the button's onClick

```
public class BottomListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private String mEmployeeNumber;
    private EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;

    public BottomListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_cardView);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mTitle);

        if (mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }

        final int position = cursor.getPosition();

        holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(8);
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(2);
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(3);
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(4);
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(5);
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(10);
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(7);
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(6);
                String mPic = cursor.getString(9);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                Toast.makeText(context, mEmployeeNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(context);
                callNewDirectReport();

            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mCardView;
    }

    private void callNewDirectReport() {
        String mDirectReportUrl = "https://b2aproxy.supervalu.com/OneTeam/OneTeamService.asmx/GetDirectReportsWithPicture";

        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(mDirectReportUrl).newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("manager_employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
        String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();


        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    final String responseData = response.body().string();
                    final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                    final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                    final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                    for (Employee e : employees) {
                        dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                    }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance the adapters are being updated before the db is updated?

Comment: I'm not doing so. I could but not sure how that helps the onClick method to update the UI with the new response.

Comment: I'm trying to understand: basically, you want to update UI accordingly to changes in your underlying database, right? Have you considered Loaders?

Comment: @Valentino S.  Do I need to create the LoaderManager within the CursorAdapter or do I need to create another class to handle this? I have been looking at some guides and I am struggling to wrap my brain around how to implement a Loader to update the UI after a web service is called.

Comment: I've just tried to give you a useful answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

They let's you bind the data source (Content Provider or other) with the Activity or Fragment. While Loaders are active they should monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the contents change.

I will give you a general approach to how implement them (CursorLoader in particular). I hope to be clear :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int LOADER_INTEGER = 1;

    // ... existing code

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_INTEGER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(
            this,
            ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

You can read a lot on internet about this, a good start is for example [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-properly-loading-data--mobile-5673).

Hope this helps!

Comment: little confused on what the CONTENT_URI and project are supposed to be. Also how does this tie into the button click when the new data is received from web service.

Comment: Do you have a content provider by which you interact with your SQLite database?

Comment: I do not, I see I need one. I went to the link you provided but see now there are is guide before hand that helps set up for the loader. I will work on this and hopefully don't need any help, if do I will create another question. Thank you.

Comment: I see that it was not clear in the explanation, also I supposed that you had a Content Provider, but thank you for accepting the answer! Fell free to ask what is not clear, I will try to answer :)